# Move folders in svn

Tags: svn, directory, move

I have the following filesystem `/svn/svn/mydata` and I want to move `/svn/mydata`. The svn is running under ubuntu.

Comment: Do you want to move the repository or SVN checkout folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the server process / client access model?  Apache, svnserve, svn+ssh?  For apache look in your httpd.conf / subversion.conf for `SVNPath` or `SVNParentPath`

`cd /etc/apache2; grep -r "SVNPa" .`

svnserve is probably with xinetd and svn+ssh would either use absolute paths or a script wrapping svnserve that points to the root.

Answer (score -1):

The command your after is svn move

[svn move — Move a file or directory.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re18.html)

Comment: Yes, it is too difficult to find a link to the **actual** svn version. Fast answer is good, but not always the first link from google is the best one.

Comment: Hi @zerkms, I was confused at first by your comment as the pages are almost identical. The link I provided _is_ from the actual svn version on on the red-bean domain. However, I can see what you mean, your link is the nightly manual from v1.6 of SVN, my link is to an outdated link to v1.0, but the link still provide all the essntial information for svn move. But i'd agree your's is a better link.

Answer (score -1):

If you're speaking about the project root: erase the old one, checkout from the new one.